# Trouble Using Apache's HttpClient with HTTPS in Web Containers

Tags: tomcat, https, junit, jetty, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using Apache's `HttpClient` version 4.2.1 to perform an HTTP POST, and I'm getting the commonly found `SSLPeerUnverifiedException`:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:352)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
    ...
```

Many solutions abound, but I think this case is different.

When I execute the code using `HttpClient` via JUnit in Eclipse or Maven, I get no errors and communicate as expected with the server in question. However when the code is run within Tomcat or Jetty (through Maven's Cargo plugin) I get the above exception.

Why is this happening, and what do I do to get past this?

Comment: I think my question might be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034849/why-do-i-get-javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-peer-not-authenticated-on